# Google Maps, js.minify, gmap.js no info shown on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using a theme that had only came with js.minifiy. I am able been able to get a marker to show however that it. No description of place nor is the label clickable. I have tried quite a few things but I cannot fix this.  Since the theme is using js.minify do i need to make changes in that file? Not sure I need an API but I did set up a Google Maps Javascript API. Should I include that in js.minify? I uploaded the default theme files for testing and help would be appreciated.

http://vineblock.trade

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', googleMapsInit);

function googleMapsInit() {
    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 17,
        scrollwheel:  false,

        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.8679988, 138.5118251),

        // How you would like to style the map.
        // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
        styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
    };

    // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map
    // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'images/label.png',
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.8679988, 138.5118251),
        map: map,
        title: 'Carros'
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the URL in the question for?  Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site (particularly without explanation, my first thought is it is spam)

Comment: You don't have any code in the posted snippet that would create or open an [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)